# Enable versioning on all lists and libraries

Tags: powershell, versioning

Is it possible to enable versioning on all lists and libraries across all web sites of a site collection? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Here is a script that can do it. Replace `$siteURL` with your site's url.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL)
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
    Write-Host "Inspecting " $web.Title
    foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
        if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {
            Write-Host "Versioning enabled: " $list.EnableVersioning
            Write-Host "MinorVersioning Enabled: " $list.EnableMinorVersions
            Write-Host "EnableModeration: " $list.EnableModeration
            Write-Host "Major Versions: " $list.MajorVersionLimit
            Write-Host "Minor Versions: " $list.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit
            $list.EnableVersioning = $true
            $list.EnableMinorVersions = $true
            $list.MajorVersionLimit = 2
            $list.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit = 5
            $list.Update()
            Write-Host $list.Title " is updated with MajorVersionLimit 2 and MajorwithMinorVersionsLimit = 5"
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/2d82272d-9aea-453a-b2ae-bf7df55a0304/

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been 3 years ago and already answered, but [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter) you can find plenty of versioning scripts and ready programs:
[Disable a versioning on Image Libraries in SharePoint using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Disable-a-versioning-on-91c47409)
[Enable versioning for all SharePoint Online lists using Powershell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Enable-versioning-for-all-ae5cfb5d)
[Enable versioning for all lists in SharePoint Online tenant (C#)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Enable-versioning-for-all-e17ebcd0)
[Restore and clean up SharePoint versions](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Restore-and-clean-up-f3c712fd)
[Enable minor versions for all SharePoint Online lists using Powershell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Enable-minor-versions-for-431d4a7e)

The scripts/codes are usually published, so you can adapt them to your needs.